# Single lane traffic intersection simulation on a given image (or created by matplotlib, cv2, etc)

Tags: python, image, intersection, traffic-simulation, motion-planning

I want to write python code that simulates single lane traffic intersection on an image that I have below. I don't necessarily need to do it with a given image, ones that are created by cv2, matplotlib, etc are fine as well.

The cars start at the beginning of green arrows, and red dots are merging points. I also show an example how they move with the red car

[image]

Currently I am still confused how I should start with this. Could anyone kindly give me hints or help me with this?

I've read about potential field, checked out PathPlanning and PathTracking of PythonRobotics on Github, but still kinda clueless about this one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I created the street by pygame with display.blit(street,(0,0)). I'm now kinda struggle with algorithms for path tracking (cars follow green/blue arrows). The link to it is https://github.com/DangTranQL/Traffic_Flow/tree/main